# Проблемы при установке manjaro linux

Tags: linux, windows, grub, manjaro

Некоторое время назад я здесь задавал вопрос по поводу перехода на линукс. Хочу попробовать посидеть на этой системе как на основной, и берется она как замена вин10. Сразу хочу попросить не минусовать за "предательство". Я вообще любил винду и мне было на ней комфортно, но последнее время захотелось чего-то попроще в плане дизайне и по мощнее в плане внутрянки. Так как макось по-умолчанию дорогая, то выбор пал на линукс. Сначала думал не заморачиваться и перейти на бубунту, так как это я думал самый популярный дистр. Дальше погуглив и изучив вопрос, набрел на Linux Manjaro KDE. Не знаю правильный ли я сделал выбор, поэтому если у кого-то будут предложения, или дельные советы буду благодарен если отпишетесь в комментах. Я пишу приложения под android (как можно понять с тематики моих вопросов) и соответственно оочень сильно переживаю по поводу возможности продолжить работу и на линуксе тоже. Но вроде бы (насколько я понял) manjaro как и остальные дистрибутивы нормально тянут все что нужно. Если у кого-то был опыт перехода с винды на линукс то буду благодарен за инфу.

Теперь суть проблемы: так как я решил сносить винду и ставить как основную систему линукс мне нужно было создать загрузочную флешку для установки. Я взял флешку на 32гб (может и меньше можно, не знаю) и для начала записал все при помощи rufus-а. Система не загрузилась. Дальше использовал программу ultraiso - система не загрузилась. При попытке запуститься вылезала ошибка:

```
grub unknown file system
```

и дальше можно было вводить только команду. Как я понял из форумов проблема в версиях grub. Но как починить это дело я не очень понял. Собственно два вопроса:

1. Стоит ли заморачиваться, и ставить эту систему как основную, если да то как решить данную проблему.
2. Какое ваше мнение касательно выбранного дистрибутива, правда ли он так хорош как про него пишут в сети, или же есть что-то получше?

Я новичок в плане перехода на другую ось, поэтому не судите строго :)

### UPDATE

Господа линуксоведы меня будут сейчас немного пинать наверное. У нас вообще база знаний, и поэтому здесь я хочу приложить решение данной ошибки которая была у меня. Суть в том что при записи линукса (я так понял все-равно какого) на флешку, выскакивает такое окошко:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и нужно выбирать именно DD метод записи. Я выбрал его, записал флешку и все нормально запустилось. Кому интересно какой [ПК](https://support.hp.com/ru-ru/document/c05402248). Может кому-то мой ответ будет полезен. Нашел [решение](https://manjaro.ru/newby-corner/grub-unknown-file-system.html) на этом форуме.

Comment: Дистрибутивы отличаются друг от друга набором софта, устанавливаемого по умолчанию (обратите внимание, не "набором доступного софта"!), и используемым менеджером пакетов. Всё. Поэтому определение "лучший линукс — это тот, который использует ближайший к вам линукс-гуру" всё ещё актуально.

Comment: Плохо, что Вы не написали конфигурацию своего компьютера, на который собираетесь устанавливать систему. Разные графические оболочки более или менее требовательны к ресурсам, проще или сложнее настраиваются. Для себя и своих друзей я выбрал Ubuntu и Linux Mint XFCE. Легкая, быстрая, хорошо настраивающаяся оболочка. Причем, замечу, что все мои друзья, перешедшие на Линукс - адвокаты, юристы, врачи - полнейшие чайники. Признаюсь, я забыл, когда решал проблемы вирусов, ошибок, глюков и прочего на их компьютерах.

Comment: Вот очень хороший пример - инженер из Нижнего Новгорода (РЖД, кап. строительство) - https://forum.xubuntu-ru.net/index.php?topic=1117.0 KDE мне как-то не пришелся - многовато оперативки жрет, много свистоперделок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добро пожаловать в семью linux )
 1. На самом деле почти любая система linux легко адаптируется под необходимые задачи, так что переживать относительно основной версии.
 Но всё же, если Вы новичёк в linux, советую выбирать что попроще, исключительно за счёт того, что при возникновении каких-либо трудностей - Вы легко сможете найти ответ в интернете. Я много перепробовал дистрибутивов linux и графических оболочек, но всё-равно суть одна. После долгих скитаний, становился я всё же на ubuntu на одной машине, немного адаптировав её под себя, Debian и kali на двух других. Данные дистрибутивы изначально несут в себе большую часть необходимых программ и утилит, что, порой, значительно облегчает жизнь. 
 2. Что касается ошибок дисков - тут необходимо понимать, что несмотря на наличие дополнительных утилит - каждая из ОС может работать как с ntfs(win), так и с ext4(linux), тем не менее формат жёсткого диска лучше устанавливать в соответствии с предполагаемой ОС. Это поможет избавится от "танцев с бубном". 
 3. Grab - это универсальный загрузчик, который сообщает Вам, что возникли неполадки при установке. Обычно, возникают они, в основном, если были изменены метрики раздела /boot или этот раздел был полностью удалён и более не существует. В интернете достаточно много информации, как можно через консоль решить данную проблему, в зависимости от того, что конкретно произошло у Вас. 
 4. Для того чтобы установить linux, я советую Вам Unetbootin. Он лёгок и прост в использовании. 
 5. Windows очень сильно ограничивает пользователя в действиях (Из разряда - я не дам тебе это сделать глупый человечишка, это всё сломает) Linux же даёт практически полную свободу действий, вплоть до sudo rm -rf /* )))
Переход на linux - это очень похвальная вещь на мой субъективный взгляд, однако, будьте готовы менять свой подход к пользованию системы ) Удачи!

Comment: а почему вы выбрали именно убунту, чем руководствовались, просто я убунту посмотрел, и там как-бы есть утилиты которые я не юзаю, и не планирую, поэтому я как-то не манжару смотрю) плюс быстродействие интересует тоже)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Если Вы переживаете относительно не используемых утилит - они достаточно быстро и просто удаляются. В любом случае, знакомство с системой linux лучше начинать с адаптации под себя. Но бывают и такие вещи, которые, чтобы установить на linux, ну прям надо попотеть. А подобные системы несут в себе почти все необходимые инструменты. Manjaro тоже неплох, все linux системы очень похожи, но я не сказал бы что он по производительности быстрее ubuntu. Особенно учитывая, что можно менять графическую оболочку по своему усмотрению ) Есть шутка - Пропатчить KDE2 под FreeBSD )))